# How can i insert values in custom table in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, table

I have created a custom table name as "my_topic" using InstallSchema now i want to insert data in this table. How can i do this please suggest your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Consider your table with title,content_heading and content field are defined,**

Now you have to pass inside `__consturct` field to your module factory object like below,
Table with below content are automatically added.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $_postFactory;

    public function __construct(\Vendor\Modulename\Model\PostFactory $postFactory)
    {
        $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Hello world!',
            'content_heading' => 'Hello world!',
            'content' => 'logn description put here'
        ];

        $this->_postFactory->create()->setData($data)->save();
    }

}
```